# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el numero de pixeles de cada color en PHP?

Tags: php, html, rgba

Estoy haciendo un programa en `php` que dada cierta imagen debe decir cuantos pixeles hay de cada color, el problema es que con el código que esta abajo me da una inmensa de los colores pixel por pixel, de este modo:

```
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
array(4) { ["red"]=> int(255) ["green"]=> int(127) ["blue"]=> int(38) ["alpha"]=> int(0) }
.....
.....
.....
```

Y lo que yo quiero es que imprima por ejemplo:

```
N pixeles de color 222,222,222
N pixeles de color 123,123,123
.....
.....
.....
```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Colores</title>
    <link href="hoja_styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<img src="colores.jpg"/><br/><br/>
<?php
$im    = imagecreatefromjpeg( "colores.jpg" );
$largo = imagesx( $im );
$ancho = imagesy( $im );

for( $x = 0; $x < $largo; $x++ ) {
    for( $y = 0; $y < $ancho; $y++ ) {
        $indice = imagecolorat( $im, $x, $y );
        $rgb    = imagecolorsforindex( $im, $indice );

        var_dump( $rgb );
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La lógica que necesitas sería 1º agrupar y contar, 2º imprimir con el formato deseado.

Esto te facilita la gestión del contenido para mostrarlo según las necesidades.

La base es generar un *contenedor* que tenga una `key` única, como pueden ser los valores `rgb`.

Comprobar en cada iteración si la `key` existe. Si existe aumentar el contador, y si no existe agregar un nuevo `pixel`.

Por último, con el contenedor creado, decidimos que formato de salida le damos y distribuimos el contenido según nos interese.

```
$im    = imagecreatefromjpeg( "colores.jpg" );
$largo = imagesx( $im );
$ancho = imagesy( $im );

// crea un contenedor
$pixeles = [];
for( $x = 0; $x < $largo; $x++ ) {
    for( $y = 0; $y < $ancho; $y++ ) {
        $indice = imagecolorat( $im, $x, $y );
        $rgb    = imagecolorsforindex( $im, $indice );

        $key = sprintf( '%s_%s_%s', $rgb['red'], $rgb['green'], $rgb['blue'] );
        // o
        // $key = $rgb['red'] . "_" . $rgb['green'] . "_" . $rgb['blue'];

        // comprobar si existe la key
        if( array_key_exists( $key, $pixeles ) ) {
            // si existe aumentamos el contador
            $pixeles[$key]['count']++;
        }
        else {
            // si no existe añadimos un nuevo pixel con sus valores
            $pixeles[$key]['color'] = $rgb;
            $pixeles[$key]['count'] = 1;
        }
    }
}

// imprimes los valores
foreach( $pixeles as $pixel ) {
    $n      = $pixel['count'];
    $red    = $pixel['color']['red'];
    $green  = $pixel['color']['green'];
    $blue   = $pixel['color']['blue'];
    $return = '<br />';
    printf( '%s pixeles de color %s, %s, %s.%s', $n, $red, $green, $blue, $return );
    // o
    // echo "$n pixeles de color $red, $green, $blue.<br />";
}
```

Como funciones adicionales se pueden comprobar el número de cada fila, y asignar `pixel` si es 1 o `pixeles` si es mayor de 1.

PD.: Si hay algún error, comenten y edito.

Comment: gracias, funciono bien, estaba probando uno donde me decía el numero de colores que tenia y me marcaba miles de colores, encontré que estaba usando jpg y al parecer con ese formato pierde calidad e incrementa el numero de colores demasiado :/ pero bueno con esto se resolvió todo y ahora si me marca el numero de colores y cuantos pixeles son de cada uno :)

Comment: Sólo me queda apuntar que es redundante usar `echo sprintf`, con `printf` es suficiente, y que tienes una errata en `$key = $rgb['red'] . "_" . $rgb['red'] . "_" . $rgb['red']`, quizá quisiste decir `$key = $rgb['red'] . "_" . $rgb['green'] . "_" . $rgb['blue']`. Sería buena idea que corrigieras eso (te llevas mi +1).

Comment: @OscarGarcia gracias por el apunte, son cosas del directo ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Lo que debes hacer es incrementar en uno un contador que se almacene en una matriz de 256x256x256 elementos (o 256x256x256x256 si también quieres incluir el canal alfa).

El consumo de memoria no será un problema porque sólo se reserva el necesario para los índices existentes, no para todos.

```
$elementos =  [];
for($x = 0; $x < $ancho ; $x++) {
  for($y = 0; $y < $largo; $y++) {
    $indice = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
    $rgb = imagecolorsforindex($im, $indice);
    if (isset($elementos[$rgb['red']][$rgb['green']][$rgb['blue']])) {
      $elementos[$rgb['red']][$rgb['green']][$rgb['blue']]++;
    } else {
      $elementos[$rgb['red']][$rgb['green']][$rgb['blue']] = 1;
    }
  }
}
/* Ordenamos las componentes por su clave */
ksort($elementos);
foreach ($elementos as $r => $rojos) {
  ksort($rojos);
  foreach ($rojos as $g => $verdes) {
    ksort($verdes);
    foreach ($verdes as $b => $numero) {
      printf('%s pixeles de color %s,%s,%s%s',
        $numero,
        $r, $g, $b,
        PHP_EOL
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Cada elemento del array guarda su índice de componente RGB, por lo que a partir del índice se conoce ese dato.

---

**Versión más eficiente**

Si deseas una versión eficiente, con el número mínimo de llamadas y operaciones, puedes tener en cuenta ésta:

```
$elementos =  [];
for($x = 0; $x < $ancho ; $x++) {
  for($y = 0; $y < $largo; $y++) {
    $indice = imagecolorat($im, $x, $y);
    // Nos quedamos únicamente con los datos RGB */
    $rgb = $indice & 0xFFFFFF;
    if (isset($elementos[$rgb])) {
      $elementos[$rgb]++;
    } else {
      $elementos[$rgb] = 1;
    }
  }
}
/* Ordenamos las componentes por su clave */
ksort($elementos);
foreach ($elementos as $color => $numero) {
  printf('%s pixeles de color %s,%s,%s%s',
    $numero,
    ($color >> 16) & 0xFF, /* Obtenemos la componente R */
    ($color >> 8) & 0xFF,  /* Obtenemos la componente G */
    $color & 0xFF,         /* Obtenemos la componente B */
    PHP_EOL
  );
}
```

El valor devuelto por `imagecolorat` es un entero cuyo valor en hexadecimal está compuesto por `AARRGGBB`, donde los dos bytes más significativos son el valor de la transparencia (canal alfa), los dos siguientes la componente R, posteriormente la G y por último la componente B.

Resultados:

```
$ time php prueba.php | tail -3
3637 pixeles de color 255,255,255
Tamaño de imagen: 1706x2560
Memoria usada: 23.66 MB
real    0m3.614s
user    0m3.268s
sys 0m0.580s
$ time php prueba_optimizada.php | tail -3
3637 pixeles de color 255,255,255
Tamaño de imagen: 1706x2560
Memoria usada: 18.34 MB
real    0m1.423s
user    0m1.176s
sys 0m0.492s
```

Se reduce el consumo de memoria en un 22% y el tiempo de ejecución en un 60%.

Comment: esta igual me ha funcionado bien, muchas gracias :)

Comment: He editado mi código para incluir una ordenación de los componentes de menor a mayor. La otra solución no soporta ordenación de este tipo y consume mayor memoria por agregar de manera redundante junto a los datos la componente que ya compone el índice.

Comment: @CarlosDayan, he agregado una nueva edición con una versión optimizada en memoria y velocidad.